# Can I Have FK in 2NF and 3NF in Relational Schema?

Tags: database-design, database-schema, rdbms, relational, database-normalization

So basically I'm Normalizing an Invoice, is it wrong to include FK *INV_NUM* in all **2NF** RELATIONAL SCHEMA'S.  This is what I already have.

the * Shows PK

**1NF** (***INV_NUM**, INV_DATE, C_ID, C_NAME,C_STR,C_STATE,PART_NUM, PART_DESC, PART_QUANUSED, PART_PRICE, LBR_NUM, LBR_DESC, LBR_PRICE,TAX_RATE)

PARTIAL DEPENDENCIES

- (C_ID--> C_NAME,C_NAME,C_STR,C_STATE)
- (PART_NUM--> PART_DESC, PART_QUANUSED, PART_PRICE)
- (LBR_NUM--> LBR_DESC, LBR_PRICE)

TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCIES

- (C_STATE--> TAX_RATE)

**2NF**
*CUSTOMER* (***C_ID**, C_NAME,C_NAME,C_STR,C_STATE)

**2NF**
*PART* (***PART_NUM**, PART_DESC, PART_QUANUSED, PART_PRICE)

**2NF**
*LABOR* (***LBR_NUM**, LBR_DESC, LBR_PRICE)

Comment: What do you mean by "transitive dependency" `C_STATE--> TAX_RATE`? A transitive dependency is between 3 attributes.

Comment: This is the Definition of Transitive Dependency in my Book

Transitive dependency 
– X-> Y, Y->Z (X is the PK) 
therefore, X -> Z is a transitive dependency 
– Transitive dependencies exist only when there 
is a functional dependence among nonprime 
attributes (e.g., Y->Z). 
• Nonprime = not a part of any candidate key 
• Candidate Key = minimal superkey

Comment: Also in the Business Rules of my Problem it said Tax_Rate is Calculated from Customer's State, so that how I arrived at that assumption.

Comment: The usual notation would be X -> Y -> Z, which _implies_ X -> Z, but not the other way around, so they are not equivalent notations. So if you just say C_STATE--> TAX_RATE, that doesn't tell us that this is supposed to be a transitive dependency, nor which is the "middle" attribute. BTW, which attributes are prime becomes important in the context of 3NF.

Answer (score 1):

> So basically I'm normalizing an invoice, ...

Actually no, not really.

Invoices are **temporal** by nature, so that `INV_DATE` is extremely important.

In other words,
FD is **not** `{C_STATE} -> {TAX_RATE}`, but `{C_STATE, INV_DATE} -> {TAX_RATE}`.

FD is **not** `{C_ID} -> {C_STATE}`, but `{C_ID, INV_DATE} -> {C_STATE}`.

FD is **not** `{PART_NUM} -> {PART_PRICE}`, but `{PART_NUM, INV_DATE} -> {PART_PRICE}`.

etc, ...

So your options are

1. Leave (the invoice table) as it is (seems OK)
2. Make all temporal.

---

It is common design for invoices (also purchase orders ...) to "capture and freeze" all relevant info at the time.